# Distance between endpoints in spatial table

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial

I need to find the cities that have a maximum distance between endpoints.

```
CREATE TABLE "cities" (gid serial,
"city_id" int4,
"city" varchar(21));
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','cities','geom','26986','MULTIPOLYGON',2);
```

Comment: Hi there. According to the [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_EndPoint.html) the function ST_EndPoint expects a LineString, and your geometry column has a MultiPolygon. Could you elaborate a bit on your use case? Perhaps you need something else.

Comment: I tried to convert the polygon to a linestring.

Comment: the 1st and last point of a polygon ring is the same point, so a distance of 0 makes sense.

Comment: @Anaidm the polygon is a closed ring, so first and last points are identical

Comment: @JGH then how can I find the correct endpoints?

Comment: what do you mean by "endpoints"?

Comment: Something like the length of the linestring, maybe? Or distance between 1st and penultimate point @JGH

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Perimeter.html

Comment: @JimJones so you're saying that I cannot find a distance between them, because it is always 0.

Comment: @Anaidm you mean this? `SELECT cities.gid, cities.city,
  ST_length(ST_MakeLine(j.point ORDER BY j.gid)) 
FROM cities,
LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(geom) j(gid,point)
GROUP BY cities.gid, cities.city` it retrieves the length of the polygon as a linestring. I'm not sure it is what you want..

Comment: @Anaidm or perhaps this `SELECT cities.gid, cities.city,
  ST_length(ST_MakeLine(j.point ORDER BY j.gid)) 
FROM cities,
LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(ST_GeometryN(geom,1)) j(gid,point)
GROUP BY cities.gid, cities.city;`

Answer (score 0):

To get a ring perimeter, you should compute the line length, not the distance between two points

```sql
select st_length(ST_ExteriorRing(ST_GeometryN(geom,1)))
```